# Unable to retrieve list item values for aa particular field

Tags: java, cucumber, gauge

I am having an issue trying to create a list for a field.

If you look below I have 3 fields but field three has two values which are suppose to be passed through as a list.

The issue is that even though field 1 and 2 passes in the single value fine the relevant field, field 3 is not passing through a list of values associated with that field. Instead it is passing through an empty array and I am not sure why. If I change it to single value, it finds the single value and works, but when I implement the `List<String> valueItem`, then it's empty array.

```
* Example step:
   |field     |value                                       |
   |----------|--------------------------------------------|
   |field1    |shop                                        |
   |field2    |apple                                       |
   |field3    |tree, cone                                  |


@Step("Example step: <table>")
public void exampleStep(Table table) {
    Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
    table.getTableRows().forEach(row -> {
        String value = row.getCell(VALUE);
        String field = row.getCell(FIELD);

        if (StringUtils.equals(field, "field3"))) {
            List<String> valueItem = Arrays.asList(value.split(","));
     for (int i=0; i <= valueItem.size(); i++) {
            body.put(field, valueItem);
        }
        }else {
            body.put(field, value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Might want to check the size of `valueItem` list. Also ensure that the name of the field is indeed `field3`; otherwise you'll get the empty value.

Comment: @Ithar I have updated the code to include the loop and I can see it has put both values in the field but I am not sure if it's put it as like one string and not two items, is the .put I am using that is causing the issue?

Comment: I have gone with a different approach but this is a good answer for anyone. Thanks